# aws DynamoDB issue while getItem

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get single Item through dynamoDB using Javascript here my code

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'sharedata',
    Key: {
        id: _id
    },
    ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
    };

ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success", data.Item);
    }
    });
```

and here my table in dynamoDB.

[image]

I am facing error: Expected params.Key['id'] to be a structure. What I am missing I am trying same as per docs  [reading writing a single Item in dynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error

```
error: Expected params.Key['id'] to be a structure
```

is indicating that key is not formed correctly in the request. From the 
[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html):

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'TABLE',
  Key: {
    'KEY_NAME': {N: '001'}
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
};
```

Try this out:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'sharedata',
    Key: {
        id: {S: _id}
    },
    ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
    };
```

Comment: thanks it's working fine, But one thing is still not clear what means S which we include for query, I found in docs there is keys S, and N do you know what is these stand for???

Answer (score 1):

The Object to be formatted in a AttributeValue representation. That means you would have to change this

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'sharedata',
    Key: {
        id: {S:_id}
    },
    ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
 };
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhinaya for your reply it's working now, one thing still not clear to me I found S in query, accounding to docs I found keys S, N do you know what are these stands for???

Comment: It represents the data of an attribute .Each attribute value is described as a name-value pair. The name is the data type, and the value is the data itself. N stands for Number datatype and S for String.